# 80's movie with a boy on skates or bmx bikes that has holographic ants that torture people

Tags: story-identification, movie

I once saw an 80's movie with a boy on skates or bmx bikes that has holographic ants that torture people. It was post apocalyptic if I recall.

Comment: The first half of your question was not promising in terms of details that would help to narrow down what movie this was. Then you came in with the holographic ants, and I felt like we had a pretty good chance there.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - When he said "BMX bikes in the future", I felt that "it's from the 1980's" was pretty unecessary

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You mean [Solarbabies](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091981/) (AKA Solarfighters) from 1986. You can see the "holographic ants" scene in the film below:

[image]

It has also this sequence with torturing an alien ball with titan nitride drilling....

Comment: @Richard Whoa, fast finding....

Comment: If you think that's good, check out the latest edit.

Comment: @Richard Now only HD, 3D & 7.1 surround is missing. Oh man, I must have seen this movie earlier despite being campy and cheesy as hell. Thanks for improving, by the way.